# I am trying to install Apex 5.1 locally but i couldn't connect as a sys user from Apex directory (ERROR: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

```
e:\apex.5\apex_5.1\apex>sqlplus no/log
sql>conn sys as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

so i couldn't continue to the next step of installing Apex.

Answer (score 1):

You should really post what you exactly did, and how Oracle responded.

This is what your code produces in reality:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus no/log

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sub Srp 10 13:19:01 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

That is, you're connecting to user named `no` whose password is `log`, and there's no such user (as Oracle responded). I presume you meant to use `/nolog`, which is something quite different.

---

Here's how it works on my database:

```
c:\Temp>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sub Srp 10 13:17:30 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
```

As you can see, no problem in connecting to the database if I provide valid credentials. I have no idea what **you** did wrong, because, there are inconsistencies in what you *say* vs. what you *show*.

By the way, why installing Apex 5.1. I'd suggest the latest available version (21.1 at the moment).